# daap server: extra_data request not being called

Tags: daap

I have implemented a daap server by using the unofficial specification which can be found here:
https://github.com/andytinycat/daapdocs

It's working with the last version of iTunes (11.1), but I have no artwork in iTunes for my daap-served albums.

I have seen that the following request is handled in several open source daap server :

```
/databases/%d/items/%d/extra_data/artwork?session-id=%d ...
```

iTunes does not send the extra_data request with my current setup. 
My question : why ? Which dmap code should I implement to make iTunes send that extra_data request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send ated=0x0001 on '/server-info' and asac=0x0001 on '/databases/1/items' at every item